# iphone uitableview - linking problems?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4

I am trying to follow a tutorial about xml parsing  http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/ . The tutorial does not explain how to link and that is the part that i am stuck on. Looking at the source code provided i can see that "view" is linked with "file owner". In MY file, when i do this, i cannot link them. It does not highlight. Does anyone know why? what are the usual causes for this? (new to iphone). Thanks for any help!

Comment: Make sure your file's owner is link to a UIViewController (customized or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this helpful http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/iphone-programming-fundamentals-outlets-and-actions

This one is specific to XCode4 but is also helpful to understand the Interface Builder basics

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/04_InspectingNib.html

If you add  a new file  (a subclass of view controller) you will get three files .h,.m and .xib. The File owner is always connected to the correct View Controller which happens to the owner of this nib(.xib) file. you can verify the same as shown in image below.[image]

If this is the case then I am sure you can always link up your new elements (labels,buttons) to the correct Outlet. Just a reminder here that the declaration should start with the keyword IBOutlet so that It shows up in the interface builder.

eq `IBOutlet UILabel         *lblTitle;`